# Laravel | <option> value is inserted in DB as NULL

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-9

So I have added a select "grade" option in my register form, however, the value is not inserted in my grade column for the user/stundent table. No errors, it only says NULL in the DB field. Here's my code:

**register.blade.php**

```
<!-- Grade -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-label for="grade" :value="__('Grade')" />

                <select class="form-control" name="grade">
                    <option selected>Select a grade</option>
                    @for($i = 5; $i < 14; $i++)
                        <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                    @endfor
                </select>
            </div>
```

**RegistredUserController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'grade' => $request->grade,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

I've also tried to add the validation for the grade field which also didn't work, would be nice if someone could help me with that :)

Comment: Should you be disabling the selected option so that they can't pick that one.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work. it's just so the "Select a grade" option is at the top

Comment: Probably you forgot add grade column to your fillable in your model.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add 'grade' to the fillable array in the model example

```
protected $fillable = ['grade',.....];
```

i hope it was useful